# Cron job generate duplicate processess

Tags: linux, shell, cron

My cron is like below:

**$ crontab -l**

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.sh 2>&1 > /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.log; echo "Exit code: $?" >> /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.log
```

**$ more /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "starting script";

/usr/local/bin/rsync -r /vas/app/check_cron/cron1/ /vas/app/check_cron/cron2/

echo "completed running the script";
```

**$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/rsync**

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 bin      bin       411494 Oct  5  2011 /usr/local/bin/rsync
```

**$ ls -l /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.sh**

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 vas     vas         153 May 14 12:28 /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.sh
```

if i run it manually ... the script is running well.

```
$ /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.sh 2>&1 > /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.log; echo "Exit code: $?" >> /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.log
```

if run by crontab, the cron generate double processes more than 30 in 24hours until i kill them manually.

**$ ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v root | grep -v grep**

```
vas 24157 24149   0 14:30:00 ?           0:00 /bin/sh /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.sh
vas 24149  8579   0 14:30:00 ?           0:00 sh -c /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.sh 2>&1 > /vas/app/check_cron/cronjob.log; ec
vas 24178 24166   0 14:30:00 ?           0:00 /usr/local/bin/rsync -r /vas/app/check_cron/cron1/ /vas/app/check_cron/cron2/
vas 24166 24157   0 14:30:00 ?           0:01 /usr/local/bin/rsync -r /vas/app/check_cron/cron1/ /vas/app/check_cron/cron2/
```

Please give me advice how to make running well and no processes still running in the system
and processes stop properly.

BR,
Noel

Comment: Are your scripts completing in a timely manner?  If they take a long time to run then they will accumulate.

Comment: the script must be completely finish in few seconds... and there is a job to check if there are duplicate processes or not. The question is why there are duplicate processes in cron job,

Answer (score 0):

The output you provide seems normal, the first two processes is just `/bin/sh` running your `cron` script and the later two are the `rsync` processes.

It might be a permission issue if the crontab is not the same user as the one you use for testing, causing the script to take longer when run from `cron`.  You can add `-v`, `-vv`, or even `-vvv` to the `rsync` command for increased output and then observe the `cron` email after each run.

One method to prevent multiple running instances of scripts is to use lock files of some sort, I find it easy to use `mkdir` for this purpose.

```
#!/bin/sh

LOCK="/tmp/$0.lock"

# If mkdir fails then the lock already exists
mkdir $LOCK > /dev/null 2>&1
[ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 0
# We clean up the lock when the script exists for any reason
trap "{ rmdir $LOCK ; exit 0 ; }" EXIT

echo "starting script";

/usr/local/bin/rsync -r /vas/app/check_cron/cron1/ /vas/app/check_cron/cron2/

echo "completed running the script";
```

Just make sure you have some kind of cleanup when the OS starts in case it doesn't clean up /tmp by itself.  The lock might be left there if the script crashes, is killed or is running when the OS is rebooted.

Comment: thanks Olafur ... i will test it.                                    $ ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v root | grep -v grep | wc -l
      46

Comment: Just watch if the lock gets very old in the /tmp dir then the script is truly stuck and then you must debug why it is getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you worry? Is something not working? From the parent process ID's I can deduce that the shell (PID=24157) forks an rsync (24166), and the rsync forks another rsync (24178). Looks like that's just how rsync operates...

It's certainly not cron starting two rsync processes.

Comment: if 2 or 3 processes is OK. but i found in the system is:             $ ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v root | grep -v grep | wc -l
      46

Comment: Then I suspect an issue with the script. Running it from cron is different than from a command line. E.g. cron-started it does not have a controlling terminal (so hangs when reading from stdin), PATH is not set, the environment is minimal, etc. Maybe it accumulates zombies over the course of a day?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CRON, you might want to have a look at the [Fat Controller](http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/)

It works similarly to CRON but has various built-in strategies for managing cases where instances of the script you want to run would overlap.

For example, you could specify that the currently running instance is killed and a new one started, or you could specify a grace period in which the currently running instance has to finish before then terminating it and starting a new one.   Alternatively, you can specify to wait indefinitely.

There are more examples and full documentation on the website:
http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/